# Once completing a Firebase Authentication, how can I post data to the signInSuccessUrl?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

I have:

```
const uiConfig = {
  // Popup signin flow rather than redirect flow.
  signInFlow: 'popup',
  credentialHelper: 'none',
  // Redirect to /signedIn after sign in is successful. Alternatively you can provide a callbacks.signInSuccess function.
  signInSuccessUrl: '/app',
  // We will display Google and Facebook as auth providers.
  signInOptions: [
    { provider: firebase?.auth?.EmailAuthProvider.EMAIL_PASSWORD_SIGN_IN_METHOD }
  ]
};
...
<StyledFirebaseAuth uiConfig={uiConfig} firebaseAuth={firebase.auth()} />
```

But when the user authenticates, how can I tell if it's a login or a first time creation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`signInSuccessWithAuthResult`](https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web#signinsuccesswithauthresultauthresult-redirecturl) callback. You can check if the user is a new user with `authResult.additionalUserInfo.isNewUser`:

```
const uiConfig = {
  signInFlow: 'popup',
  credentialHelper: 'none',
  signInSuccessUrl: '/app',
  signInOptions: [{ 
    provider: firebase?.auth?.EmailAuthProvider.EMAIL_PASSWORD_SIGN_IN_METHOD
  }],
  callbacks: {
    signInSuccessWithAuthResult: function(authResult, redirectUrl) {
      const isNewUser = authResult.additionalUserInfo.isNewUser;

      // Do something with the returned AuthResult.
      // Return type determines whether we continue the redirect automatically
      // or whether we leave that to developer to handle.
      return true;
    }
  }
};
...
<StyledFirebaseAuth uiConfig={uiConfig} firebaseAuth={firebase.auth()} />
```

Comment: What's the `type` for `authResult`?

Answer (score 0):

#### firebaseui.auth.AuthResult

You can check this in lib [readme](https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web#signinsuccesswithauthresultauthresult-redirecturl)